# Use Knockout.js to generate table content according to the combobox choose

Tags: javascript, html, json, knockout.js

I would like to have a combobox button (controled by Knockout JS) which defines the
content of a HTML table. I've tried to build this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smSgj/1/)
unsuccessfully.

**HTML:**

```
<br>Groups:
<br>
<select data-bind="value: selectedFruitGroupId,
                   options: groups,
                   optionsText: 'name'"></select>
<br>
<br>Fruits Group:</br>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fruit</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: selectedFruitsGroup">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: weight"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
ViewModel = function() {
    this.selectedFruitGroupId = ko.observable();

    this.groups = [
        {name:"A", id:0},
        {name:"B", id:1},
        {name:"C", id:2}
    ];

    this.fruitsGroups = [
        {
            id: 0,
            fruits: [
                { name: 'Apple', weight: '80' },
                { name: 'Orange', weight: '100' },
                { name: 'Banana', weight: '140' }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            id: 1,
            fruits: [
                { name: 'Pear', weight: '80' },
                { name: 'Melon', weight: '100' },
                { name: 'Grapes', weight: '140' }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            id: 2,
            fruits: [
                { name: 'Mango', weight: '80' },
                { name: 'Kiwi', weight: '100' },
                { name: 'Coconut', weight: '140' }
            ]
        }
    ];

    this.selectedFruitsGroup = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.fruitsGroups, function(fruitGroup) {
            return fruitGroup.id == this.selectedFruitGroupId();
        })[0];
    });
}
```

Then, I would like that when choosed "A", it is showed "Apple", "Orange" and "Banana".
When choosed "B", it is showed "Pear", "Melon" and "Grapes". And when choosed "C", it is showed "Mango", "Kiwi" and "Coconut".

Very best regards.

Answer (score 4):

Use the optionsvalue binding in the select element and set it to id

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedFruitGroupId,
               options: groups,
               optionsText: 'name', 
               optionsValue: 'id'"></select>
```

heres an updated fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/QmF9V/3/

Comment: @ragnarok56 I saw your code, what about if the number of columns it's dynamic?